# Angular 7 intercept - How to fix duplicate HttpClient calls when making a request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am using an interceptor with HttpInterceptor in angular 7 and I have a problem where all my http requests are duplicated.

This is for Angular Version 7.2.14 with typescript.

```
declare var require: any
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserRoles } from '../models/Companies';
import { AuthenticatedUser } from '../models/AuthenticatedUser';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

interface LoginResult {
    bearerToken: string;
}

interface ResetResult {
    response: boolean;
}

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<LoginResult>;
    password: string;

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResult> {
        return this.http.post<LoginResult> 
   (`${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/authenticate`, { username, password }, 
    httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(token => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to 
                     keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', 
                    JSON.stringify(token));

                    this.currentUserSubject.next(token);
                }
                return token;
            }));
    }
}
```

[Image of my duplicate request calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eellH.jpg)

[Image of network requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8dwf.jpg)

As you can see it is suppose to make one request but it is currently firing off duplicate requests every time.

Comment: I think you are supposed to share a screenshot of the network tab; not the console tab. Please share the network tab screenshot.

Comment: You can seen: Login State in Angular 7: http://hoanguyenit.com/login-state-in-angular-7.html

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the network tab as well

Comment: I was able to solve this. I found out in my interceptor i was calling next.handle(request) twice.